# Global Asax vs Global Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

My application is written in MVC5.

I've noticed that my Global.Asax file is slowly filling up with code as the application grows.  Particularly there's a lot of code accumulating in the Application_EndRequest that do things like logging, setting response headers, and some security/authentication things.

I want to know if this sort of stuff can be safely moved into a set of global filters?  I've not used global filters before, but they seem a neat way to do this kind of code in a testable and encapsulated way.

So:

- is the Global.asax Application_EndRequest directly equivalent to a global filter's OnActionExecuted method?
- What are the considerations when choosing between a global filter and Application_EndRequest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's up to your needs. Ok. I would try to answer your questions:

1. is the Global.asax Application_EndRequest directly equivalent to a
   global filter's OnActionExecuted method?

> No. As the name suggested, Application_EndRequest is called in the end of the request, while global filter's OnActionExecuted is called as per controller executed.

2. What are the considerations when choosing between a global filter and Application_EndRequest?

> Depends on your needs. If you need to do something after the each controller called ended, then can use the filter, if you only need to do something at the end of the request once, just put it in the global asax EndRequest.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please could you give example of "something after the each controller called ended" and "something at the end of the request once"?